# Сохранение и предпросмотр картинок с LocalStorage

Tags: javascript

Использую вот этот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/8V9w6/
После загрузки файла, появляется предпросмотр, все работает нормально, но как только страничка перегружается, предпросмотр остается, а вот файла нету.
Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка. Заранее спасибо.

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    // Only process image files.
    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
        // Render thumbnail.
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
          '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'
        ].join('');

        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        localStorage.setItem('img', e.target.result);
      };
    })(f);

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
if (localStorage.img) {

  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML += ['<img class="thumb" src="', localStorage.img,
    '" title="test"/>'
  ].join('');

  document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);

}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```

Comment: Не воспроизводится. У меня работает.

Comment: Та пример то работает, но файла нету после перегрузки страницы, только предпросмотр

Comment: Хм, файл сохраняется в хранилище, выводится предпросмотр, что не так?

Comment: У меня в проекте тоже так, но если добавить файл и не перегружать страницу, на сервер он уходит. Если же страницу перегрузить, предпросмотр остаётся, а вот файл на сервер уже не идёт.

Comment: Даже в примере после перегрузки страницы написано "файл не выбран"

Comment: О каком сервере идет речь? Не вижу в этом коде ничего что могло бы работать с сервером.

Comment: Сервер tomcat. В проекте используется форма с добавлением файлов как в указанном примере. Когда в заполненной форме есть ошибки, сервер возвращает страничку с указанием ошибок, тоесть перегружает ее. Вот после такой перегрузки предпросмотр картинки остаётся, но после успешного заполнения формы, на сервер файл уже не передается. В то же время если форму изначально заполнить правильно, файл на сервер уходит. Похоже на то, что при перезагрузке страниц из localStorage воспроизводится уже не файл

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сохранение прикрепленных файлов после обновления html/jsp страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718359/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-html-jsp-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)