# Сохранение прикрепленных файлов после обновления html/jsp страницы

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp

Есть некая форма на html/jsp, которая предусматривает загрузку картинок. Также реализована проверка правильности заполнения полей. В случае ошибок, страница направляется обратно пользователю с указанием ошибок.

Работа с картинками реализована с предпросмотром. В случае ошибок на странице, изображение для предпросмотра подтягивается из localStorage. Все реализовано на Spring MVC+jsp+js.

Теперь вопрос: если на странице есть ошибки, она фактически обновляется. При этом, прикрепленные картинки пропадают, а предпросмотр работает (из localStorage). В то же время, информация в текстовых полях остаётся. Когда ошибки исправлены, все уходит на сервер tomcat. На сервере текстовые поля с формы приходят нормально, а вот файлы не приходят вообще. Если же изначально заполнить форму корректно (без обновления страницы) то файлы приходят на сервер как положено.

Можно ли каким-то образом сохранить прикрепленные картинки в виде файлов после обновления страницы?

Comment: Изображения надо сохранять после перезагрузки страницы. Сохранять можно на клиенте(в браузере) или на сервере, других вариантов нет. Поскольку сохранять на клиенте чревато всякими проблемами и сложностями(например в Safari, в приватном режиме не работает localSorage), лучше всего сохранять на сервере. Т.е. вы сохраняете изображения на сервере, еще до сохранения всей формы с данными.

Не оформляю как ответ, потому что может есть решения по лучше, а я его не знаю)

Comment: Это понятно, но приклепляют то их до перезагрузки страницы. А если перегрузить ее, уже прикрепленных файлов нету. Пока вижу только вариант грузить Аяксом на сервер сразу после прикрепления файла к форме. Но что тогда делать если пользователь меняет файл или вообще закрывает браузер?

Comment: Если будете использовать вариант с сервером, то нужно использовать `ajax` для предварительного сохранения изображений. Но раз вы можете использовать `ajax`, то используйте его и для сохранения формы! В таком случае страница не будет перегружаться - пропадет куча проблем! И появится другая куча))